# cakephp : how to add other query

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

i have a model, controller and view of employee.
each employee has : `id, name, dateofjoin, dateofbirth, religion, address`, etc.

in `employee/index` -> I got all employee listed, but only some of the fields are listed (id, and name). on the right side, i have button "view" to see the detail.

when i click the "view" button, it will show me the detail of all fields :id, name, dateofjoin, dateofbirth, religion, address, etc.

what i want is : i need to put additional information which are :
- how many years this man has been working for us ?
- how old is he ?

dont worry, i have the query to do it. but i dont know where to put the queries.

in plain query, i have :

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(NOW(),'dateofjoin')

SELECT DATEDIFF(NOW(),'dateofbirth')
```

they two will show me the answer, but once again, where and how do i have to put the queries ?

Comment: First of all, i doubt your queries will work, you have to remove the quotes around dateofjoin and dateofbirth, these are table names, not strings. How does your controller looks like?

Comment: hi davey, yes i know it wouldnt work. i know my dateofjoin/birth should be something like '1998-12-12'. that's not the problem. i understand. my question is how to put the queries ? should i put them on controller / model ? my controller is still the standard one, nothing change yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use virtual fields [see manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html)

in your model

```
public $virtualFields =  array(
    'age' => 'DATEDIFF(NOW(),dateofbirth)',
    'working_time' => 'DATEDIFF(NOW(),dateofjoin)'
);
```

and in the controller

```
$this->Employee->find('all', array('fields' => array('id', 'name', 'religion', 'age', 'working_time'));
```

Comment: where to put those line in the controller arilia ? i put them under public function view ? am i wrong ? the error is : parse error, right on the controller line.

Comment: i edited because i missed the model name. You have to put those line in your view function. I assume you already have a `$this->Employee->find(...)` function call. You just have to add the fields list and include virtual fields

Comment: what i have is model Employee. and i already put `public $virtualFields` in it. then i put `$this->Employee->find(...)` in the EmployeesController. still it cannot work. in EmployeesController there is `public function view($id = null)` and the last line was `$this->set('employee', $this->Employee->read(null, $id));` i think we close to it.  Please your next instruction. or is it allowed if i ask you through skype ?

Comment: hi arilia, eureka ! :) no need to put a line in the controller. only public virtualfields. many thanks :)